# How to implement a function that checks if the system is consistent or not?

Tags: python

inconsistency in python.

I'm trying to implement a function for gaussian elimination.

This function should test if the matrix is inconsisten or consistent.

We assume that the input is in echelon form so we don't need to worry about fowardElimination.

How can i loop through to and check that given row is all zeros ?

This is what i have so far..

```
def inconsistentSystem(A):
    """
    B is assumed to be in echelon form; return True if it represents
    an inconsistent system, and False otherwise
    """
    a = A.copy()
    m, n = np.shape(a)
    for r in range(m-1):
        for c in range(r,m):
            for k in range(r, n):
                if(a[c][k] == 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Completely different idea - we can define consistency based on the rank of matrix. If the ranks of augmented matrix and coefficient matrix are same, we can say that the system is consistent.

Since numpy is already being used, we can directly find the ranks of both matrices with `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank` method and return the result.

```py
def inconsistentSystem(A):
    '''
    A is assumued to be the augmented matrix
    All rows of A, and all the columns but the last shall be the coefficient matrix
    '''
    return np.linalg.matrix_rank(A) != np.linalg.matrix_rank(A[:,:-1])
```

Hope this helps.